# Assembly retrieving buffer to c function parameter

Tags: c, assembly, x86, 32-bit, calling-convention

I'm writing an assembly function that will read from IDE through ports.

I'm calling the parameters through x86 base pointer (EBP).
I debugged my kernel.bin (with gdb and qemu) and I that when I'm calling my recv buffer to print, eax will return values like:36h01h10h

[IBM Char Table](http://www.ascii-codes.com/)

My disk.asm is divided by read and write. Is it possible that I'm writing it wrong? Is it legal to move directly [ebp+16] to esi (to write)? If I, on read function, move [ebp+16] directly to edi is wrong? I'm using a register poiting to that address and making edi to point to that register:

In my disk.asm, to read the disk I have this:

```
sub dx, 7 ;dx = 0x1f0
mov ecx, 256
mov edi, bufferrecv
rep insw
(...)
push ebx
mov ebx, [ebp+16]
mov [ebx], long word bufferrecv
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

And to write disk:

```
sub dx, 7 ;dx = 0x1f0
mov ecx, 256
mov esi, [ebp+16]
rep outsw
(...)
```

I'm declaring those functions this way:
Kernel.c

```
extern int _readd(int sector_count, int nmrsector, STRING in_msg);
extern int writed(int sector_count, int nmrsector, STRING out_msg);
```

The STRING type was declared inside my types.h as char*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is it that function returning me random values in eax (like 36h 01h 10h). If I compile it, it will return me random values to eax (each time I change my code of course)

Comment: Which function? You describe multiple functions. Please consider editing your question to be clearer. Right now, I have absolutely no idea what you want to ask. Read your question and ask yourself if someone else than you understands what your question is about.

Comment: You still have a system with IDE interface? Wow!

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh!!  THAT IDE.   I thought 'Integrated Development Environment':)

Comment: If you want something to be returned in eax, you should put it there. I don't see any code that does this.